# Godot: How to get mouse button input for a Tilemap for Cellular Automata

Tags: tilemap, input, mouse, godot

**Conway's Game of Life**

I have been working with a tilemap for the implementation of a cellular automata game. My current method for getting mouse button input is using an Area2D as a child of the Tilemap and detecting mouse button input like that.

I have done this and have since been wondering if there is something built in that I can use for this. I have looked into it and cannot find anything better.

Is there something built-in to Node2Ds or Canvas Items that I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way would be to override `Node._unhandled_input()` and use `TileMap.world_to_map()` and `TileMap.map_to_world()` methods.

Example:

```
# tile_map.gd
extends TileMap

func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT and event.pressed:
            var clicked_cell = world_to_map(event.position)
```

Do note that `world_to_map()` takes a local position. Node2D supplies the `to_global()` and `to_local()` methods to ease the conversion.

I recommended using `_unhandled_input()` rather than `_input()` so gui input events are not passed through to the tile map. If the the tile map is undesirably receiving mouse events when you interact with a control, make sure that the control's `mouse_filter` property is not set to "Ignore".

Comment: And if I have controls that sometimes overlap the tilemap. your solution was what I tried out before I ran into that problem. So you have any way around that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you expand on what problem you face when controls overlap the tilemap?

Comment: I click on the controls and end up setting one of the tiles underneath it.

Comment: The events shouldn't propagate to `_unhandled_input()` unless if all the Control's that overlap have their mouse filter property set to ignore.

Comment: I must have been doing it wrong then. Thank you. I was not using unhandled input previously.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110377/discussion-between-kennichi-nitta-and-hola).